# Phone softbricked after updating TWRP

Tags: boot, fastboot, twrp, micromax-yu-yureka

My Yu Yureka is stuck at boot logo after I updated to TWRP 3.2.0.0.

It does not go into recovery or download mode. I tried connecting it to PC and that too isn't working.

How do I flash a working version of TWRP to a softbricked phone?

Comment: I got stuck in Logo Screen after updating TWRP 3.2.0.0. This video help me to Recover my phn and get back my old TWRP recovery.. :)﻿ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nfPEKRUKLQ

Answer (score 0):

Does the Yureka have Fastboot mode, or the Samsung's Download mode you mean, and if its MTK based, you can read how to flash it using SP Flash Tool via Preloading an Image or Fresh ROM

Answer (score 0):

You can use fastboot methods via adb command prompt on Windows, make sure you're flashing the right version twrp for your device 
Things to check :
- latest twrp
- 32-bit or 64-bit (based on your Android version) 
- kitkat /lollipop /marshmallows /nougat /oreo based on your current Android version.

Answer (score 0):

Recalling from my own experience, I think this is caused due to the fact that Yureka initially has KitKat(32-bit) and the TWRP recovery you're trying to install isn't compatible with it. I too suffered from this. To fix this, I first updated to Lollipop(which is 64-bit) and then tried flashing the newer recovery. It worked!

Yureka YU CM12 ROM(Lollipop):http://www.techofire.com/yu-yureka-ao5510-firmware/

> This answer is purely based on experience, and may therefore be incorrect(explanation-wise). Corrections are welcome. Though I can assure the OP that the procedure works.

Comment: I'd also like to add that I first I flashed a relatively older TWRP recovery(~v3.0.2) for installing LineageOS 14.1, and it was after that, that I was able to flash the latest recovery(currently v3.2).